# How to enable cors in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I need to display contents alone of a word press site in another HTML page in other web application. How to embed that particular div in my application

Comment: The question is too broad and does not have a specific problem for us to solve. Have you tried implementing this?

Comment: Yes.. suppose a WordPress page is there.. need to embed the content content in article tag without header and footer , I need to embed in another HTML page within spring web application. I am trying using iframe

Comment: Used iframe and jQuery load.facing issues in jQuery load due to cors issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery load I mentioned the div .In. Header.php of WordPress site added the line Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *